# SQL Server ssmssqlproj

Tags: sql-server

I want to open the project file `.ssmssqlproj` in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Developer edition. While opening it gives the error that `ssmssqlproj` is not installed.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Can you please post the **complete and exact** error message you're getting?

Comment: The application for project ... is not installed                         ,make sure the application for the project type (.ssmssqlproj) is installed

Comment: I have upgraded from express to developer edition

Comment: Also I don't have the file -> new -> project option

Comment: @Millerbean I also have the same issue. Found any solution?